# What can i get from the waste land?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I sent out 4 people who are pretty high level into the wasteland earlier today. They have been gone for a couple of hours and just wanted to know what are the chances of them coming back with high end hear like power armor or wrestling suits. I will bring them back in about two days. Thanks any answers will help.

Comment: How many rare items you find depends greatly on the dweller's luck.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/235885/88641 Just might be of interest here :P

Answer (score 1):

Well if you just send them out for a few hours, you probably will get just scrap as everything. The level doesn't count in that case.

The level will increase their life, which will help them to survive in the wasteland. The longer they'll survive, the better equip can (! - not will) be found.

I normally send my best guys out for 2 days or longer. They normally will find 2-3 good things and many crab during those 2 days.

Normally after 1 1/2 day they start to find occasionally good things. Things like a flamethrower, machine guns, gausse weapons, etc.

By the way, equip them always with maximum stimpacks (25) and around (13-15 rad-aways). You'll get everything back which is left over, after their expedition.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: I have been told that dwellers don't get damage or radiation sickness when returning to the vault, so you could leave them out there until they are 95% irradiated and on 1% hp before recalling them and they will get home just fine :)

Comment: Yes your right. I've seen the same things on my expeditions. You can revive them even if they die. But this will waste lot of corks. But anyway I would suggest to give them enough rad-aways. It will help them to survive as long as possible. :-)