# Is this a bug or is it luck?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I sent out a lvl 7 dweller to explore the wasteland. I just picked up some resources and when I just started looking how it is actually going (~5 minutes later) it read something about "let's check the metal chest" and then I found a destabilizer. After a bit research I figured out that this pistol is one of the best weapons.

One point that made me a bit mistrustful is the point of the log when it happened.
It says 00:-05.

So is it just a kind of glitch/bug I encountered or am I just a lucky guy that found while exploring the wastelands for 5 minutes the strongest non heavy weapon with a guy that just has a luck stat of 1?

Or the third option: Is getting legendary loot after a few minutes isn't that rare as I expected it?

Comment: I'd say RNGesus was in your favour.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this but the developers

Comment: I would also be satisfied by an answer explaining that there is no evidence that this is a known bug.

Comment: If the log says _negative_ five minutes, then it wouldn't sound too farfetched that the game interpreted that as having been out for an infinite amount of time. Personally, I have never seen anything rare or better drop in the first hours of a run.

Comment: @Svj0hn: exactly that is the point why I was thinking maybe I wasn't lucky in RNG terms, as the negative time is kinda unusual...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an exploitable bug called "The Negative Time Glitch". It occurs when you already have an explorer who is about to find an item shortly, and you deploy a second (or more;)) explorers. They hijack the timer, and also are rewarded with an item. The timer, however, for them, since they just got out of the gate hasn't quite started yet, and is registered as a negative number. Basically, they are being rewarded as if they had been out for the maximum amount of time. It's hard to replicate, you got lucky!

Answer (score 8):

Well there doesn't seem to be anyone reporting this bug, I looked on their entire support forum and then searched on their entire forum (Fallout Shelter) and no posts available:  http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?app=core&module=search&section=search&do=search&fromsearch=1

This can mean 2 things:

1. The bug exists but no one reported it because they're enjoying too much the situation :)
2. The bug doesn't exist and you were among that 0.000000001 chance of dropping a legendary item in the first 5 minutes. Almost like winning at the lottery without actually having the money :D

Kudos to you!

Answer (score -1):

If it is a bug, the same thing more or less happened to me. I sent out 4 level 1 dwellers without any supplies since I didn't have any at the beginning of the game, forgot about it, opened up a day later to find them unsurprisingly all dead. 2 had died after ~70 minutes. The other 2 lasted 12 hours and had picked up a Fat Man and Focused Gatling Laser.

Since the other two dwellers died so early, I can only assume that the 2 lucky dwellers picked up the items early and the high level of the items allowed them to walk an additional 11 hours. I thought something was up to but there has been nothing out of the ordinary so far.

Comment: But the main reason that made me perplex was not the item itself it was the time log which stated a negative value.